# Can tightly coupled fragments be okay in Android (under certain circumstances)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, interaction

When implementing Fragment to Activity communication the usually told example is:

```
MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {
  ...
  @Override
  public void myMethod() {
  // Do something....
  }
  ...
}

MyFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
  private void aMethod() {
    ((MyInterface) getActivity()).myMethod();
  }
  ...
}
```

The fact is that more often than not in my projects Fragments are used merely to decompose an existing activity in different modules in a "divide et impera" fashion (maybe during refactoring when the activity has become too complex). Attaching one of these fragments to another activity (different to the one from which the fragments have been extracted) will simply not make any sense.

So in my cases I usually end up with:

```
MyActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  void myMethod() {
  // Do something....
  }
  ...
}

MyFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
  private void aMethod() {
    ((MyActivity) getActivity()).myMethod();
  }
  ...
}
```

So the dreaded question is: Why do we have to use an interface if the Fragment will always be used only inside that activity? Is this bad practice? What are the advantages of using an interface in these cases?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a bad practice. What are you trying to solve when you use an interface? You try to foresee the cases when you will use the fragment with some other activity. If this isn't happening, then your interface only adds complexity without any benefits.

One other benefit is probably defining which methods the fragment can call on the activity, so your interface is well-defined. However, the benefits of that are debatable.

Additionally, I usually group the activities and fragments by function together in one package. So if I were writing this, I would have `myMethod` package private, which obviously can't be done with an interface. So in a way it even improves encapsulation.

Comment: `myMethod()` was actually package private in my code, I forgot to properly report it in the question. I'll edit it.

Comment: @MarcoRomano I'll still leave this information in the answer, I think it's important to emphasize it. I think people sometimes overengineer things, and while I agree that decoupling is a good practice in general, it is not necessarily a mistake to not do that it in simple cases. The simplest solution that works is sometimes also the best.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we have to use an interface if the Fragment will always be used only inside that activity?

You don't have to use an interface in this situation.

> Is this bad practice?

For you in this situation, no.